# The required anti-forgery cookie &quot;__RequestVerificationToken&quot; is not present in JMeter

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, performance-testing

[image]

JMeter is not able to process request. Its showing error

```
The required anti-forgery cookie &quot;__RequestVerificationToken&quot; is not present
```

in JMeter, while same provided in HTTP Cookie Manager element. Ihave added

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that your application is protected by a form of [CSRF attack prevention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

Bypassing CSRF protection with JMeter isn't a rocket science, it is classic [correlation](http://artoftesting.com/performanceTesting/correlation.html) example. I would recommend to follow the next steps:

1. Add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) Listener to your test plan
2. Execute test plan
3. Open very first request in View Results Tree listener and look for something like `__RequestVerificationToken`
4. Once found fetch its value via on of the following post processors:

   - [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)
   - [XPath Extractor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)
   - [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor)
5. Once you have token extracted and stored into a JMeter Variable add a [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) as a child of the **next request** and configure it as follows:

   - Name: `__RequestVerificationToken`
   - Value: Reference Name of the variable used in the extractor from step 4. I.e. if Reference Name was `token` put `${token}` into Value input.